# How do you copy Latitude Longitude from the old SXA fields to the new Coordinate fields?

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions

We are upgrading from an older SXA for Sitecore 8.2.7 to SXA 9.3. We would like to keep the `Latitude` and `Longitude` values intact but we have hundreds of items with this data.

How can I migrate these values over using SPE to get our search working again?

Answer (score 2):

You may notice on the IPoi items that they now inherit from the template `/sitecore/templates/System/Geospatial/Coordinate`. If you created custom items which inherit from this template or perhaps you used the OOTB template you should see multiple latitude/longitude fields.

Use the following script as an example on how to migrate the field data.

**Example:** The following finds descendant items at a specific root and then copies the field data. Here we are dealing with items representing jobs on our Career site.

```
# Change to the root ID for items which use the IPoi template
# Careers
#$rootId = "{B8208D4B-C25E-4381-A183-4177E47A9310}"
# POIs
$rootId = "{60365D59-F2F2-4C49-91DA-9C7B046178CF}"

# Change to the template ID of the items inheriting from IPoi
# Job
#$filterId = "{0CB1F725-2A60-49D9-8BC4-867F5FDF73FA}"
$filterId = "{6EBB38CE-04FC-425C-895B-3C81FA4A7B5C}"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:" -ID $rootId -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.TemplateId -eq $filterId }
    
foreach($item in $items) {
    $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
    # SXA does not have a constant available for the Latitude/Longitude fields so we use the hardcoded ID.
    $item.Fields[[Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.Constants]::Latitude].Value = $item.Fields["{94969C59-C4B8-43ED-9C92-3FBF930C0ACF}"].Value
    $item.Fields[[Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.Constants]::Longitude].Value = $item.Fields["{8C1AEA63-2E5E-4FEE-B413-D3B1E050DD26}"].Value
    $item.Editing.EndEdit() > $null
}
```

**Note:** Be sure to crawl all the content again now that the new fields contain data.

#### Bonus

**Example:** The following snippet shows a scriban template for the `Place` object using schema.org.

```
{{ poi = sc_follow i_page "POI" }}
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
  <div itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
    <meta itemprop="latitude" content="{{ poi | sc_field "Latitude" }}">
    <meta itemprop="longitude" content="{{ poi | sc_field "Longitude" }}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need it only if you have custom template for your POIs. By default there is an upgrade script which will copy field values automatically:
`/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/SXA - Upgrade/Functions/Upgrade Scripts/Migrate POI coordinates`